# How to fix this SettingWithCopyWarning:

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, warnings

For this function:

```
def get_unique_df(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    unique_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Value', 'Label'], keep='first')
    unique_df.index = range(len(unique_df.index))
    unique_df['Label'] = unique_df['Label'].astype(int)
    return unique_df
```

I'm getting this warning:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I've done some research and feel like the line `unique_df['Label'] = unique_df['Label'].astype(int)` is the issue but I'm not sure what to change it to, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try unique_df = `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Value', 'Label'], keep='first')[:]`

Comment: Try `unique_df.loc[:,'Label'] = unique_df['Label'].astype(int)`

Comment: this resolves the warning because the colon notation `[:]` creates a copy of the df separate from the original, whereas in your code, unique_df is being set equal to a slice of the original df. `unique_df = df.copy().drop_duplicates(subset=['Value', 'Label'], keep='first')` would also work